# Fitting differential equations: how to fit a set of data to a differential equation in R

Tags: r, differential-equations

With a data set:

```
conc <- data.frame(time = c(0.16, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3), concentration = c(170, 122, 74, 45, 28, 17, 10))
```

and I would like to fit this data to the differential equation below:

```
dC/dt= -kC
```

where C would be the concentration, and time t in the data set. This would also give a result of k. Could anybody give me a clue how to do this in R? Thanks.

Comment: Please use `=` inside `data.frame(.)`, *not* `<-`.

Comment: This seems to be homework.

Comment: Actually it's not homework. Data is the most simplified one-compartment model in pharmacokinetics. The reason I put a simple example is that I believe similar methodology could be utilized to solve multiple compartment problems, and hence some linked models in PK-PD simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution:

```
    require('deSolve')
conc <- data.frame(time <- c(0.16, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3), concentration <- c(170, 122, 74, 45, 28, 17, 10))

##"Model" with differential equation
model <- function(t, C, k){
  list(-k * C)
}

##Cost function with sum of squared residuals:
cost <- function(k){
  c.start <- 170
  out <- lsoda(c(C=c.start), conc$time, model, k)
  c <- sum( (conc$concentration - out[,"C"])^2)       
  c
}

##Initial value for k
k <- 3
##  Use some optimization procedure
opt <- optim(k, cost, method="Brent", lower=0, upper=10)

k.fitted <- opt$par
```

Maybe it is a bit naive since using lsoda seems to be a bit overkill for calculating with only **one** differential equation... But it certainly optimizes your k. 
You might want to check the start value for C for the integration, I set it to 170 here, don't you have a value for t=0?

Comment: Thank you very much. I just found that modCost function in FME could also be a solution, although not as straight-forward as the answer you provided. http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/FME/docs/modCost

Comment: Do you have any reference on how to do this for multiple parameters? Or, can you spend a few minutes on this question and tell me where I am wrong about it? Thanks.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730793/fitting-differential-equations-how-to-fit-multiple-parameters-to-a-differential

Comment: The line `c <- sum((conc$concentration....c.170..122..74..45..28..17..10. - out[,"C"])^2)  ` inside the cost-function is wrong. I corrected it to be: `c <- sum( (conc$concentration - out[,"C"])^2) `, but I don't know when it will be peer-reviewed and thus visible.

Answer (score 1):

First use separation of variables to solve the differential equation. This gives log(C)=-k*t+C0.

Plot the data:

```
plot(log(concentration) ~ time,data=conc)
```

Fit a linear model:

```
fit <- lm(log(concentration) ~ time,data=conc)
summary(fit)

# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   5.299355   0.009787   541.4 4.08e-13 ***
#   time       -0.992208   0.005426  -182.9 9.28e-11 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.01388 on 5 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared: 0.9999,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.9998 
# F-statistic: 3.344e+04 on 1 and 5 DF,  p-value: 9.281e-11
```

Plot the predicted values:

```
lines(predict(fit)~conc$time)
```

Extract k:

```
k <- -coef(fit)[2]
#0.9922081
```

[image]